# Eclipse CDT won't run compiled exe files

Tags: c, eclipse

So I decided to install the Eclipse CDT as my chosen IDE. However, it seems like once I began to start running a C program that required input, Eclipse decides to stop running the files in the console window. I tried closing all the instances of the program in Task Manager, and the exe file I found on my computer works well. I tried to build the file, then run but Eclipse said that I had "nothing to build". Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length, width, height, volume, weight;

    printf("Enter the length of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("Enter the height of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Enter the width of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    volume = length * width * height;
    weight = ((volume/166.0) + 0.5);

    printf("Volume(cubic inches) %d\n", volume);
    printf("Dimensional weight(pounds): %d\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the "nothing to build" error is due to the fact that nothing (that would affect the compiled program) has changed since you last built it.  `make` functions similarly.  What are you doing to run the file?  Run->Run Last Launched?

Comment: Run->Run as->Local C/C++ Application

Comment: @Andrew I take it that the answer below was not the right answer? Have you found a solution? Can you please share it with us? I am adding a more detailed question to SO, on a similar vein. If I find an answer, I will put it up on this question too!

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it worked:

Goto Run - Run Configuration - C / C++ - Your Exe

Click on the tab "Arguments"

In the workspace section uncheck "use default"

Then select the directory where the exe resides e.g. debug

[image]