# Run .exe file of C code using Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, exe, eclipse-cdt

I've make a very simple basic code in C language using Eclipse IDE.

Eclipse details:

- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
- Version: Juno Service Release 2
- Build id: 20130225-0426

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Runs successfully in Eclipse, it generates .exe & .o file in Project/Debug directory. I am trying to run that .exe file but it is not working.

Eclipse acts as if it ran the program very quickly and then terminates it. Window appears, but nothing happens when I run the .exe. It just looks like a flash of a dialogue box.

What should be the problem? I don't want to change the IDE and I've already tried these two things:

- [Eclipse CDT won't run compiled exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670950/eclipse-cdt-wont-run-compiled-exe-files)
- [eclipse won't run my exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564977/eclipse-wont-run-my-exe-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the program from the command prompt window. If you simple double click the exe file .. it just runs the program and shuts out in an instant. You won't have any time to see it.

Run it through a `cmd` window by navigating to the directory and doing `./yourexefile`

Or a terrible way **to do this with double click** is to do this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
   int n;
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   scanf("%d",&n); // this will force the execution window to stay open until you put in some input
   return 0;
}
```

You could also do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Another way ( more aesthetic ):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   printf(" Press enter to exit\n");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for this, it works. But I've one question... Do I need to do this for all my applications??? Suppose,I want to build a calculator then also I need to do this??? Or only for those applications which aren't having any input from user???

Comment: if you want to double click to work then yes, you have to do this . These are the only two methods to make double click work.

Just put them in before `return 0;` and leave a comment like I did , why you put it there. .. also if you agree with an answer then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Windows is opening a command prompt for your program, running your print statement, and then closing the window (because your function is over).

If you want to see the result of your program, run the command prompt, navigate to the directory of your .exe file, and run it from there.

Comment: Hello Red Alert,
Thank you for your answer sir/mam.
Is there any other way to do this.
I mean, I simply want to double click my .exe file and it should run...
I am using windows 8.
BTW I tried with cmd and it gives me the output... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should also try this:

Right click on your project name in the **Project Explorer** view, then go to Run As and click on **Local C/C++ Application**